# How to solve my dependencies problem using Maven and slf4j with OWLAPI on Eclipse please

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, owl-api

First of all, I'm a newbie with Maven, so I apologize if I misunderstood something.
In a recent question I ask about the import of OWLApi in my Java project and people told me to use Maven to import it, instead of importing JAR file.
I tried a new Maven Project and imported to test OWLApi and it worked well.

Today, for my profesionnal project, I managed to work with Maven. I converted my project to Maven, added OWLApi in my dependencies... and when I build with Maven, I got the error :

```
Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError
```

Moreover, my classes are not compiled anymore (impossible to run my classes, because no .class are compiled).

If it helps, this is my pom, where I tried to excluse slf4j, as I found in another question. But it didn't help me :

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
</exclusions> 
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You had been excluded that what it needs.  you should find diff between slf classes. Excluding is very dangerous solution. Not a complete solution.  check the dependencies carefully. and download the source codes and build your own jars.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm whether this is the whole set of dependencies for your project? The artifacts mentioned do not appear in the OWLAPI dependencies, so the exclusions will not work and they must be coming from other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the classpath contains two adapters, one that passes logging calls done with Log4J to a SLF4J logger, and one that does exactly the reverse. With both in the classpath, any logging call would go first to one logging system, then be passed to the other, and this would create an infinite loop. This would result in a stack overflow, which is what the error message is reporting.

OWLAPI doesn't import either jar, it only imports the SLF4J API, so the conflicting jars must be dependencies of other libraries.

You have tagged Eclipse here, so I assume you're using Eclipse. When you open a pom file in Eclipse, you get a tabbed editor, with one tab being Dependency Hierarchy. You can use this tab to look for the jars you wish to exclude, the tab will show which of your dependencies are bringing in the jars, so you can put the exclusions in the right place. It should be sufficient to exclude one of the jars (it depends on which logging system you mean to actually use).

Comment: Hi.
First of all, thanks for your answer, I really apreciate it ! And sorry for the time I took to answer, I was very busy these days...
So, in the project, we use geotools (we were using a Jar, but I added it with Maven now). In the classpath, I use Graphsteam jars. Before I tried to import OWLAPI and used Maven, the rest was working well. So I don't understand the problem here...
I clicked in the tab you told me (Dependency Hierarchy) and the only time where sl4j appears, is the sl4j-api used in owlapi and its dependencies (jcl-over..., jsonld-java, sesame-util). 
What did I missed pls ?

Comment: If there's no other occurrence in the maven dependencies, it must be that the error is coming from a different classpath, e.g., if the code you're running is going via the eclipse project setup and that's out of sync with the maven settings. Ensure the project is tagged as a maven project and that you right click on it and select maven/update project. Else we'll need to see the content of the .classpath file in the project.

Comment: The error on Maven building is : "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/.../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/.../eclipse/java-2021-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]"

Comment: My buildpath contains only 2 java projects, which don't use Maven. In my main project, now, I use maven to import Geotools. In one of the java project I import, it uses a JAR of Geotools. Is that probably a problem ? Should I recommend the maintainer of this project to use maven, to avoid collisions with my project that newly use Maven ?

Comment: I just tried to create a fresh new maven project, with OWL Api as the only one import. I've the same :
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/.../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.0.20210618-2246/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/.../eclipse/java-2021-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

Comment: Can you share the whole pom file for this new project?

Comment: I'm facing the same isssue. I can build my project locally but in jenkins server I'm getting the below error. SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: @poojasingh That's not the same problem, it's the opposite problem. Rednayt has more than oneSLF4J binding in the classpath, you do not have any. The link in the error message explains how to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried the instruction written in the documentation but couldn't able to fix it.

Comment: @poojasingh can you post your pom file in a new question or raise an issue on the OWLAPI github tracker with it? Comments don't have enough space to discuss it.